# Flowgear Insert form post data into database

Tags: json, database, flowgear

How to insert post data into database using flowgear API? I am done inserting data using get but html form post method is not work using flowgear API. Please explain how it is acheive in flowgrear.

I have this URL

http://www.somedomain.com/api/flow-test

When I hit enter it is return JSON value

```
{
  "message" : "message send successfully",
  "statusCode" : "1"
}
```

This JSON value store into database using flowgear post method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to POST some data to a Flowgear API endpoint and then ingest that into a database, add the special property FgRequestBody on to a Variable Bar to receive the POST data.

If it's in JSON format, use JSON Convert to convert it to XML, then push it through a transform (XSL Transform or QuickMap) if it's layout doesn't match your target database.

Finally, use an SQL Table Update to insert to the data into the database.

Comment: thanks for ans.@Daniel
i am using http://domain name/projects_dev/demo/flowgear/flowgear.php this url and call my flowgear workflow.
in flowgear.php page i write
"https://yourvanitydomain.flowgear.io/yourrestfulpath/",
 "flowgearuser@domain.com",
 "password",
 30,
 array(
  "input1" => "some string value",
  "numericvalue" => 123
 ));

Answer (score 0):

When calling a Flowgear Workflow using an API call, the Workflow can respond with a specific body using the `FgResponseBody` and `FgResponseContentType` variables on the Variable Bar.